# Vue component state freezing when moved between router-views

Tags: vue.js

I have a custom map component, which wraps a Openlayers 4 instance. This component which I am forced to use, is used multiple places across my SPA. The initialization process is quite long, so I would like to keep one instance of the map available, and move it between views when I need to. Problem is that the state doesen´t update within the component when it has moved.

I´ve boiled the problem down to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j16d4yto/ 
When moved on the same router-view the state updates fine (click the ‘Change text’ button). But when the router-view changes, and the component is moved with appendChild to the new div, the state freezes, and you can´t update the text variable anymore.

This is how I move the component from one element to another:

```
this.$root.$on('showMoveableComponent', function(element) {
      element.appendChild(thisElement);
      this.text = 'Changed text2';
    });
```

I bet I am doing something wrong here, and probably also approaching this problem in the wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information about `openlayers map component` implementation. Do you use third-party components (like `vuelayers`) or your own?

Comment: I´ve updated my question with a little more detail. I am not using vuelayers.The focus should be on solving the jsfiddle problem though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because of when `router-view` changed your `MoveableComponent` has been destroyed only its DOM element still referenced by you. You can test by print something in `destroyed` lifecycle callback function.

So this mean you can solve this by using built-in `keep-alive` component:

```html
<keep-alive>
  <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/awsgt9nL/)

The `keep-alive` component will cache everything which may not good in some other cases.

In my opinion the better way to solve this is create another Vue instance and move it.

```
const MoveableComponent = new Vue({
  el: '#some-id',
  template: `...`,
  data: { ... },
  methods: {
    changeText() {
      ...
    },
    moveTo(element) {
      element.appendChild(this.$el)
    }
  }
})
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xjqazv04/)

Comment: Thanks alot! I can see that it´s working nicely in the updated jsfiddle. However, I´m having an issue getting it to work in multiple files. In a moveableComponent.vue file I am exporting the component: 
export const MoveableComponent = new Vue({
And then importing and using it in the main.js file:
import MoveableComponent from './moveableComponent.vue';
Vue.component('MoveableComponent', MoveableComponent);
But when I try to access the component in another component with MoveableComponent.moveTo(this.$refs.place2);  - MoveableComponent is undefined. 
Show to split it up?

Comment: Used the approach from this article: https://tahazsh.com/vuebyte-handy-global-components
And now it seems to be working.